# Is documentation available on files and directories in the Opera profile folder?

Tags: opera, documentation

To optimize backups on Ubuntu, I need to know what files and directories can be skipped.

Mozilla has a nice [documentation of the Firefox profile folder](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Profile_folder_-_Firefox#Files_and_folders_in_the_profile). Is such a page available for Opera? The closest I could found is [How to Migrate Opera Settings](http://operawiki.info/MigratingSettings) , but it's not that extensive. For example, what is `temporary_downloads` for? Holding downloads until these are completed?